# Why does AWS Athena not like my string fields?

Tags: c#, amazon-athena

I’ve pushed a bunch of gzipped tsv files to S3 where Athena is parsing them.  However, the string fields are just not working as expected.  Any equality operation or LIKE operator just doesn’t work at all.

**TABLE:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Archives.Events(
    Id string,     --intentionally string
    DateCreated string,
    EventType smallint,
    EventDescription string,
    UserId int,
    UserName string
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` int, 
  `month` int, 
  `day` int)
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    fields terminated by '\t' 
    lines terminated by '\n' 
location 's3://mybucket/Archives/Events'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

**PROBLEM:**

Athena has parsed everything.  Now let's imagine there's a username of 'foo'.

```
--nothing returned
Select *
From events
Where username = 'foo'


--nothing returned
Select *
From events
Where username LIKE ‘%foo%’


--records returned
Select *
From events
Where username LIKE ‘%f%’


--nothing returned
Select *
From events
Where username LIKE ‘f%’
```

I built the files in C#, encoding them with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`.  Additionally I gzipped them using `GZipStream`.  Perhaps I should try recreating the table using varchar, but `string` seems to be the recommended type for...well, string fields!

Comment: It looks like no query is returning results, are you sure you've set up the table correctly? Does `SELECT * FROM events LIMIT 10` return anything? Your table is partitioned, have you added the partitions? What do you mean by "Athena has parsed everything"?

Comment: @Theo - Yes - select all returns all columns/records perfectly (visually at least).  My third example actually returns records matching on only one letter.  It must be an encoding issue but I'm not sure where to tweak that.  I stored the files as UTF8 gzipped.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your fields are quoted. [`LazySimpleSerDe`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html), which is what you get when you say `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED`. `LazySimpleSerDe` does not strip quotes from fields.

Either you'll have to change the data to not have quotes, or use [`OpenCSVSerDe`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html), which supports quotes.

Comment: I appreciate the input here and you taking the time to dig into a little.  The issue was an encoding one, however.

Comment: @BlackjacketMack - how did you resolve the issue , the input file for me is UTF-16 encoded

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the issue was the encoding.

**(BAD) Encoding.Unicode = String fields were returned in Athena but not searchable.**

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            writeToStream(rows, streamWriter);

            bytes = compress(memoryStream);
        }
```

**(GOOD) Encoding.UTF8 = String fields are returned and searchable.**

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writeToStream(rows, streamWriter);

            bytes = compress(memoryStream);
        }
```

Comment: In C# Encoding.Unicode is two bytes per character. So 'foo' becomes six characters  'f\0o\0o\0' when interpreted as UTF8.